# how to access nested array/object and filter non empty elements of array like NaN,null,0

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Below is the array of objects. what we have to do is to

1. create an array that contains all the non-empty elements of array arr with value not equal to null, NaN, 'undefined' and 0
2. remaining in the second array

```
var arr = [
  { id: 15 },
  { id: -1 },
  { id: 0 },
  { id: 3 },
  { id: 12.2 },
  {},
  { id: null },
  { id: NaN },
  { id: "undefined" }
];
```

what I have tried is

```
var obj1 = {};
 var prop1 = [];
 var prop2 = [];
  arr.forEach(el=>{
      if(el.id!==0 || el.id!==null || el.id!==undefined || el.id!==NaN){
          prop1.push(el)
      }
      else{
          prop2.push(el)
      }
  })
  console.log(prop1)
  
  console.log(prop2)
```

but it is not working

output I receive -

> 1] [{id: 15}, {id: -1}, {id: 0}, {id: 3}, {id: 12.2}, {}, {id: null}, {id: null}, {id: "undefined"}]
>
> 2] []

expected -

> 1] [{id: 0}, {id: null}, {id: "undefined"}]
>
> 2] [{id: 15}, {id: -1}, {id: 3}, {id: 12.2}]

Comment: Please add what you are getting as an output when you console.log(prop1) and prop2

Comment: Instead of writing "it is not working", please describe in detail what the expected outcome vs. actual outcome is.  If you get any errors list them explicitly.

Comment: Think about all the things that satisfy `(x !== 0 || x != null)`  You are currently thinking about all things. ;) You likely intended `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: Do you understand why `el.id!==0 || el.id!==null || el.id!==undefined || el.id!==NaN` will **always** be true?    Consider: `(x !== 1 || x !== 2)`  You meant `&&`.

Comment: Did you **REALLY** mean to include the string `"undefined"` or did you just mean `undefined`?  That seems a little bit weird.

Comment: @Wyck yes u r right i should have used && instead of ||. and I mean include string "undefined"

Answer (score 2):

You can cast to boolean (`!el.id`) which will handle most cases and you have to deal with `"undefined"` separately:

```js
var arr = [
  { id: 15 },
  { id: -1 },
  { id: 0 },
  { id: 3 },
  { id: 12.2 },
  {},
  { id: null },
  { id: NaN },
  { id: "undefined" }
];

var obj1 = {};
 var prop1 = [];
 var prop2 = [];
  arr.forEach(el=>{
      if(!el.id || el.id === "undefined"){
          prop1.push(el)
      }
      else{
          prop2.push(el)
      }
  })

  console.log(prop1);
  console.log(prop2);
  console.log(prop1.length);
  console.log(prop2.length);
```

Comment: It's all fine. `prop2` represents non-empty elements so the count that gets returned is `4`, whereas `prop1.length` returns `5` (you can run my script to see that)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var arr = [
  { id: 15 },
  { id: -1 },
  { id: 0 },
  { id: 3 },
  { id: 12.2 },
  {},
  { id: null },
  { id: NaN },
  { id: "undefined" }
];
let filterArray = arr.filter((el) => {return !el.id || [0,null,"undefined",NaN].includes(el.id)});
console.log(filterArray);
let filterArray1 = arr.filter((el) => {return el.id && ![0,null,"undefined",NaN].includes(el.id)});
console.log(filterArray1);
```

Comment: Edited to use `.includes` as we can add what we want in it for ease.

Comment: Edited further to handle blank entry!

Answer (score 0):

why does it not work? Is the ordering incorrect or is there a JavaScript error?

The code looks fine at the first glance, you may use
if (!el.id), which checks if the id is "falsy" (0, null, undefined, NaN, false)

You may also have a look at the methods "map" and "filter",
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map